# Is it true that after a person returns from Hajj or Umrah, all his supplications (i.e. dua's) are accepted for 40 days?

Tags: quran, hadith, authenticity, reference-request

I have heard that after a person returns from performing Hajj or Umrah, all of his supplications (dua's) are accepted for 40 days.

My question is that is this piece of information authentic? Does it have a basis in Quran or Hadith?

Comment: This sounds like a myth at least I've never heard something like that.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thank you very much. This website does not give me the option of upvoting your comment unless I earn a better reputation. So inshaAllah, when I do, I'll do that.